# looping through gridview does not always work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Not sure what is causing this I have tried a few suggestions none seem to help. I have debugged my application dozens of times and the problem never occur while debugging everything steps through just fine. But when I publish my application and allow people to use it is when the problem occurs and it is not for everyone just randomly decides that a checkbox is not checked and skips the whole process also on the front end I have a validation that requires at least one checkbox to checked before the button_click will fire so I know that they had to have one checked.

Gridview

```
 <div id="divEventDetail">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdEventDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="EDID" Width="381px" OnRowDataBound="grdEventDetail_RowDataBound" GridLines="Horizontal">
    <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EventID" Visible="False">
           <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblEventID" runat="server" Text='<%#     Eval("EDID") %>'></asp:Label>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Register" ItemStyle-CssClass="template-center">
           <ItemTemplate >                         
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRegister" runat="server"/>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Wait List" ItemStyle-CssClass="template-center">
           <ItemTemplate> 
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkWaitList" runat="server" />   
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

CodeBehind

```
 protected void registerEvent()
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdEventDetail.Rows)
            {

                CheckBox chkR = row.FindControl("chkRegister") as CheckBox;
                CheckBox chkW = row.FindControl("chkWaitList") as CheckBox;

                if (chkR != null && chkW != null)// It is a datarow
                {

                    GridViewRow Rowr = ((GridViewRow)chkR.Parent.Parent);
                    GridViewRow Roww = ((GridViewRow)chkW.Parent.Parent);

                    if ((chkR.Checked) || (chkW.Checked))
                    // if ((((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkRegister")).Checked == true) || (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkWaitList")).Checked == true))
                    {
                        Label eventID = row.FindControl("lblEventID") as Label;
***Then i do my database stuff here
```

Comment: May I see your gridview image?
I want to know why the code refers multiple row `Rowr` and `Roww`.

Comment: You might be running in cross-browser issues. I would suggest adding some logging and also asking which Browser your clients are using.

Comment: Initially I thought the same thing and well so far I have tried firefox,IE6,IE8,IE9,IE10,IE11,Sarfari,GoogleChrome seems to be working in all of those at least.

Comment: didn't get the issue you are discussing. Would you mind adding some more detail about what your users are experiencing.

Comment: I have a gridview that has a template field with a checkbox in it and I am looping through this to find all checkboxes that are checked but for some reason every now and then the .CHECKED does not register even though the checkbox is checked but this does not happen all the time its random and i cant pinpoint why

Comment: What do you mean by CHECKED does not register?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the `grdEventDetail` `GridView` doesn't have `CheckBoxes` in each row. For example, `HeaderRow` and `FooterRow` probably don't have those CheckBoxes.

I would rewrite the code to eliminate any error:

```
protected void registerEvent()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdEventDetail.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkR = row.FindControl("chkRegister") as CheckBox;
        CheckBox chkW = row.FindControl("chkWaitList") as CheckBox;

        if(chkR != null && chkW != null)// It is a datarow
        {
            GridViewRow Rowr = ((GridViewRow)chkR.Parent.Parent);
            GridViewRow Roww = ((GridViewRow)chkW.Parent.Parent);

            if ((chkR.Checked) || (chkW.Checked))  
            {
                //Your code goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry afzalulh this did not end up working I had 10 people register and 2 of them broke and 8 worked

Comment: Where is the `lblEventID` in your `GridView`? I can't see it!

Comment: sorry I have other template fields that I did not put to not clutter the code but they are basic labels with eval statements in them

Comment: How do you populate the GridView? If you databind it in Page_Load, make sure that you have wrapped the code in 'if(!IsPostBack){}`.

Comment: Yes I have wrapped it inside this sorry I would like to post all so you dont have to guess but it is a lot of code so I am trying to just post the code that I think is relevant to my issue

Comment: Can it be that client side validation is failing now, not server side?

Comment: Ok after hours of debugging I am getting closer it looks like sometimes my button click decides to call my dropdownlist selected index changed event which is re binding my grid. Now I just have to figure out why on the button click it sometimes decides to fire that

Comment: after some searching I found it is a common issue thanks for taking the time to help I marked yours as correct